# Microsoft Word Printing on command line

Tags: cmd, ms-word, flags

As you know we can automatically send a docx file to printer via MS Office Word command line orders:

```
"WINWORD.EXE" /q /n "doc.docx" /mFilePrintDefault /mFileCloseOrExit
```

Can we also set the printing amount/count on the command line? Is there any to do it?

Comment: When you press Alt+T, M, M, and _In Macros In_ choose _Word Commands_. Do any of them do what you want.

Comment: I want to do it on the command line

Comment: This is a programming forum not a user forum. Ask on https://superuser.com. You didn't look at all or you would have noticed you are calling two items from that list in your command line.

Comment: I'm using this codes in my JavaScript Electron application

Comment: That list still contains your options. You can add your own to it.